# LINUX : Restart Gui app from a ssh console

Tags: linux, putty

I've a graphical program who has launched inside of the Front-End session.

I want to restart this application from putty, I can stop it by kill but I'm not be able to start application inside of the Front-End session.

When I Call application I get this error : cannot connect to X server

Comment: Do you just want to restart the X Server ? Or re-start your  application?

Answer (score 0):

This may be way too late, but you can do it with these steps.

```
xhost +localhost
export DISPLAY=:0
restart_your_app_here
```

xhost command ensures your X server will take connections from the localhost.

export tells the X server where to send the X traffic (which is its own localhost).

Third command just restarts your app, you may want to do this in a tmux or screen so that the session doesn't get killed when you log out or get disconnected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it comes too late. I've solved my problem by another way.